# PeaZip Archive File Utility break Windows Explorer Jumplist on Windows 10

Tags: windows-explorer, windows-10

I am having an issue with the PeaZip fie utility taking over the jumplist of Windows Explorer on Windows 10. The jumplist has several pinned locations. They are Download, Desktop, Documents, and Pictures. Whenever I click on them, PeaZip opens. I have uninstalled PeaZip and tried it, and it seems to resolve the problem, but reinstalling it causes the problem to come back. How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: ask this the support of PeaZip. They have to support Windows 10.

Comment: @magicandre1981 They do support Windows 10.

Comment: It seems that the problem is temporarily resolved by completely disabling system integration, although I would like a more long-term solution.

Comment: @DavidB - Your problems seem to indicate they do not fully support Windows 10 though.

Comment: again, call their support and tell tem your issues with Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

from Windows 7 onward PeaZip uses by default new context menu model https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144171(VS.85).aspx#static_cascading

In Windows 10 previews I'm testing, it seems for some reason PeaZip's subcommands for Directory class are given the precedence over MS subcommands when using the jumplist, causing PeaZip to open instead of File Explorer.
It also seems there is no way to tell Windows what subcommand it should use, which is quite strange.

In current versions, when installing PeaZip (or running Options > System integration) you can de-select "Cascaded menu" to switch to classic menu entries (does not trigger the issue), or check the "No context menu" option in Context menu screen.

In future releases I'm testing, as possible solution, moving the subcommands to Directory class to Folder class, which seems not interfering with jumplist.

Comment: Thank you. I'll do what you said as a workaround and see if a future release resolves the problem I am having. Also, do Windows 10 jumplists work differently in the background? I've noticed that the jumplists on programs I have pinned to my Classic Shell Start Menu, specifically Google Chrome, seem to not be displaying them properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is resolved here. Implementing it under "Folder" resolves it. See:

[Why does my static shortcut menu handler overwrite the Windows 10 Jumplist behaviour? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/1057945/why-does-my-static-shortcut-menu-handler-overwrite-the-windows-10-jumplist-behav/1057951)