# Why does my static shortcut menu handler overwrite the Windows 10 Jumplist behaviour?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, windows-registry, shell-extensions

I recently wanted to add a new command menu to my right click menu to have the possibility to securely delete files and directories using Sysinternals [SDelete](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/sdelete.aspx).
Using the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144171%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#cascade_subcommands) and [Regedit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Registry#Editing) I created a new menu item in my registry with a submenu containing my SDelete command.
I did this for the filetype `*` as well as for `Directory` in order to be able to delete files and directories. So far everything worked well and my new menu worked for files and folders.

However when I later wanted to open my profile using the Explorer jumplist in the taskbar, I realized that instead of opening my explorer it invoked my SDelete command on my profile (at that point in time I was glad I added a 5 second delay before the execution ;-)). Basically all Explorer jumplist entries behaved like that.

I tracked down the problem to my directory handler but still can't figure out the problem. You can reproduce the issue by saving the following code into a .reg file and execute it. *Please only do so if you know how .reg files work and can manually undo the changes!*

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\sysinternals]
"MUIVerb"="Testmenu"
"SubCommands"="mySubCommand"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\mySubCommand]
@="A Command that should do sth."

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\mySubCommand\command]
@="cmd /K \"echo mySubCommand has been invoked\""
```

**Can anybody tell me what I am doing wrong and how I can avoid this jumplist behavior?**

Comment: You're the 3rd to ask this (in any forum). See my response/fix for this issue. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/custom-context-menu-for-folder-conflict-with/13065124-24e5-4dea-85b1-412f582b49df

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This certainly is a bug in Windows 10, and I've see a couple of cases before. The workaround is to implement the verbs in Folder or AllFilesystemobjects, rather than under "Directory". See my response at Microsoft forums for the same issue.

[Custom Context Menu for folder conflict with windows default behaviour - Microsoft Community](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start/custom-context-menu-for-folder-conflict-with/13065124-24e5-4dea-85b1-412f582b49df)

[Cascading Menu And File Explorer Jump Lists Issue In Windows 10](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/cascading-menu-jump-lists-issue-windows-10/) (Has a better illustration)

Comment: Your response not only solved my problem, but also contains a better solution to implementing the menu - thank you!

Comment: Glad that helped, Fabian.